# Page jumps down when I click on a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on a link on a page a lightbox pops up. But the page also jumps to the end of the page. 
In the console the following error shows: `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`
 
You can see this on [meor.org](http://meor.org/homepage-features/for-parents) if you click on the image under 'letters from parents'

How do I stop the page jumping down when I click on the link? 
I'm using SliderPro on a wordpress site. Here is my code in the page. 
Please have a look at the live site. 
Thanks

```
[slider_pro_lightbox] <h3 style="text-align: center;">Letters From Parents</h3> 
<a class="slider-pro-lightbox-26">
  <img class="size-medium wp-image-7529 pointer aligncenter" src="http://xxx/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/letters.jpg" alt="letters" width="300" height="200" />
```

Comment: Can you show some HTML and JS code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin Quform Form Builder was causing the error. It looks like a jquery conflict.